# Loading script dependencies in react after component mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependencies, paperjs

I am attempting to use the PaperJS library with my ReactJS project.

It seems that I am running into an issue where the component has not yet mounted, and I am attempting to access the canvas of that component via PaperJS. (Reference: [TypeError _currentStyle null](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1164) )

My React component is:

```
import React from "react";
import Paper from "paper";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

class AnimationCanvas extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    animate(){
        var path = new Paper.Path();
        path.strokeColor = 'black';
        var start = new Paper.Point(100, 100);
        path.moveTo(start);
        path.lineTo(start + [ 100, -50 ]);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="AnimationCanvas">
                <Helmet>
                    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
                    {this.animate()}
                    </script>
                </Helmet>
                <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AnimationCanvas;
```

Helmet puts anything inside of the "Helmet" element into the head of the html.

This follows the [PaperJS Example](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
<!-- Define inlined PaperScript associate it with myCanvas -->
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
    var path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    var start = new Point(100, 100);
    path.moveTo(start);
    path.lineTo(start + [ 100, -50 ]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I run the paperscript after making sure the canvas is loaded, in a React-compliant way?